# Using mailto in a mobile web application running on iPhone

Tags: iphone, mobile, web, mailto

I am developing a web application to run in standalone/full screen mode on an iPhone and I am using mailto to open the default iPhone e-mail client to be able to send an e-mail from the web application.  This works, but the problem I am facing is that after the e-mail is sent, there is no way to automatically get back to the web application that caused the e-mail client to be opened in the first place. The user has to manually click the web application icon on the home screen to go back to the web application, which is not what I want to happen. Is there a way to automatically return to the web application once the e-mail has either be sent or cancelled?

If not, it appears to me that this destroys the usefulness of even using mailto in a mobile web application.  What would be the point if you cannot even get back to your web application (where you left off) after sending the e-mail?

I am using iOS 7.0.3 btw.

Comment: Your presumption is correct this is not possible.

Comment: Yes, I agree and I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically return to the web application once
>   the e-mail has either be sent or cancelled?

No, unless you develop yourself the mail app (like GMail app does with Chrome, for example)

Comment: For me, this kills using mailto from the client.  They might as well remove mailto entirely from the API if this is the way it is going to be implemented.